# VBA Skippin second stacked Do Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am self-learning VBA and would like to figure out why the second do loop does not get executed when I run my code, pasted below:

```
Sub Cellhasvalue()
    Dim msge As String
    Dim ccellcount, rcellcount As Integer
    Dim end_count As Integer
    ccellcount = 0
    'end_count = 5
    msge = "il"
    rcellcount = 3

    'For cellcount = 0 To endcount
    Do While Range("A1").Offset(rcellcount, ccellcount).Value = msge
        Range("A1").Offset(rcellcount, ccellcount).Select
        MsgBox ">> " + CStr(ccellcount) + " Has Value"
        ccellcount = ccellcount + 1
    Loop
    'Next cellcount
    MsgBox "FIN>> " + CStr(ccellcount)
    rcellcount = 0

    Do While Range("A1").Offset(rcellcount, ccellcount).Value = msge
        Range("A1").Offset(rcellcount, ccellcount).Select
        MsgBox ">> " + CStr(rcellcount) + " Has Value"
        rcellcount = rcellcount + 1
    Loop
    MsgBox "FIN>> " + CStr(rcellcount)
End Sub
```

This is basically the excel table that I'm checking on and it starts at cell A1

```
il  il  il  il
il  il  il  il
il  il  il  il
il  il  il  il
il  il  il  il
il  il  il  il
il  il  il  il
il  il  il  il

il  il  il  il
```

Comment: reset ccellcount = 0  before starting the second do loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are checking cell E1 for value, and it is empty:

```
Do While Range("A1").Offset(rcellcount, ccellcount).Value = msge
```

this, with your current variables, translates to:

```
Do While Range("A1").Offset(0, 4).Value = "il"
```

Which is cell E1, which in your example, is empty. So the while loop, since the condition is not met, immediately exits.

Setting ccellcount to 0 could solve your problem.

**In future, to understand what a code does:**

- Use the F8 key to step through the code line-by-line. Then you can mouse-over a variable to see its current value.
- You can also use watches (right click on any highlighted element, and Add Watch) - then monitor its value in the Watches window.
- You can use the Locals window (View/Locals window) to display the values of local variables.

Comment: thanks it didn't click in my mind and I like the F8 suggestion 